# Registering and Storing External Claims in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using Facebook auth and trying to register the user token as a claim but can't seem to get it to work right. I was able to get it working by manually adding it in the LinkLoginCallback method of the Manage controller provided by the default MVC template, but that approach seems cumbersome and incorrect, especially in removing and updating the token.

I've read everything I can find but the documentation on this is really lacking and I think I have the code written as it's supposed to be but it never actually registers and stores the claim in the DB. The solution I'm working with at the moment is as follows in my Startup.Auth:

```
var fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        fbOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_photos");
        fbOptions.AppId = "[myappid]";
        fbOptions.AppSecret = "[myappsecret]";
        fbOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken",
                                                     context.AccessToken));
            }
        };
        fbOptions.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbOptions);
```

Comment: Did you get any joy with this? I cant seem to store anything in claims for some reason.

Comment: Ended up having to manage it in the LinkLoginCallback, removing them manually, and only allowing initial account creation with a local account rather than an OAuth account.

Comment: Ive had a bit of success after days of googling. So it doesnt seem to work when I use my facebook account (possibly because I'm the administrator of the FB app) but it seems to work ok with other users. The next question is going to be how to correctly use the facebook token I now have in the claims system, as they expire pretty quickly...

Comment: I'm looking at this way too long, but still haven't figured it out. Claims don't end up in database and I can't access them from any controller.